# DocuSign API EmailBlurb

Tags: docusignapi

I have an envelope with multiple signers.

I want to include an emailblurb that is custom to each signer.

Is that possible?  It appears emailBlurb has to be the same for every signer.  But I would like to put a custom field, or something similar in emailblurb so I can pass in variables.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this within the recipient node with **recipientEmailNotifcation**

More information here:
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/create/#parameters_recipientemailnotification

Comment: Thanks so much.  That's exactly what I needed.